# How to get text from a stat table on another website

Tags: php, html, text, scrape

I want to scrape text from this page: http://blues.nhl.com/club/player.htm?id=8455710, specifically the number in the "Win" category and the "OT" category, then take the numbers I get, multiply the Win number by 20,000, and the OT by 10,000, add them together and display the result.

The reason I'm doing this is because the goalie that the stats are for (Marty Brodeur) is getting paid a bonus of $10,000 per point he earns the team in goal, so 20K for a win (2pts) and 10K for a loss (1pt).

I'm thinking the code would be something along the lines of.

```
<?php 
  $get_file_contents( "http://blues.nhl.com/club/player.htm?id=8455710" );
  $item ['wins'] = (path-to-object);
  $item ['OT'] = (path-to-object);

  $item ['wins'] * 20,000 = $item ['win_bonus'];
  $item ['OT'] * 10,100 = $item ['OT_bonus'];

  $item ['win_bonus'] + $item ['OT_bonus'] = $item ['bonus'];

  ?> 

<?php echo( '<h2>$item['bonus']</h2>'); ?>
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, maybe it is generated using JavaScript. Find the source of it.

Comment: It seems like they don't want you to take it, even with curl the response is bad

Comment: @baao Ok, thanks for trying, looks like I'll need to just update it manually, not the worst thing in the world.  EDIT:  What if we tried grabbing it from the hockeyreference.com stats? link: http://www.hockey-reference.com/players/b/brodema01.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PHP Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) to parse the URL and then locate the XPath (you can find the XPath using Chrome debugging and selecting the item you want.

Download the Simple HTML DOM PHP file from [Here](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=218559) and then use the following PHP Code:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$page = file_get_html('http://blues.nhl.com/club/player.htm?id=8455710');

$win = $page->find('//*[@id="wideCol"]/div[4]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]', 0)->plaintext;
$OT = $page->find('//*[@id="wideCol"]/div[4]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]', 0)->plaintext;

echo("Win: " . $win . PHP_EOL);
echo("OT: " . $OT . PHP_EOL);
?>
```